# ACRA report not found on own server

Tags: android, acra

I have implemented ACRA using [this](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)
I have added code in my application, log is saying that report file is uploaded

here is the log :

```
05-04 11:38:02.890: D/dalvikvm(3171): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 9% free 6508K/7111K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
05-04 11:38:02.900: D/ACRA(3171): About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
05-04 11:38:02.900: D/ACRA(3171): Mark all pending reports as approved.
05-04 11:38:02.900: D/ACRA(3171): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.white.xspl.sonyjive/files
05-04 11:38:02.900: D/ACRA(3171): #checkAndSendReports - start
05-04 11:38:02.900: D/ACRA(3171): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.white.xspl.sonyjive/files
05-04 11:38:02.910: I/ACRA(3171): Sending file 1399183682000-approved.stacktrace
05-04 11:38:02.930: D/dalvikvm(3171): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 9% free 6498K/7111K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
05-04 11:38:02.930: D/ACRA(3171): Waiting for Toast + worker...
05-04 11:38:02.970: D/dalvikvm(3171): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 9% free 6484K/7111K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
05-04 11:38:03.000: D/dalvikvm(3171): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 16K, 9% free 6531K/7111K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
05-04 11:38:03.000: I/dalvikvm-heap(3171): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.486MB for 65552-byte allocation
05-04 11:38:03.030: D/dalvikvm(3171): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 76K, 10% free 6519K/7239K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
05-04 11:38:03.030: D/ACRA(3171): Connect to http://mylocal.ip/reportpath
05-04 11:38:03.120: D/dalvikvm(3171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 379K, 10% free 6535K/7239K, paused 23ms+2ms, total 52ms
05-04 11:38:03.120: D/dalvikvm(3171): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
05-04 11:38:03.150: D/dalvikvm(3171): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77K, 11% free 6501K/7239K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
05-04 11:38:03.160: D/ACRA(3171): Sending request to http://mylocal.ip/reportpath
05-04 11:38:03.250: D/ACRA(3171): #checkAndSendReports - finish
05-04 11:38:03.350: D/ACRA(3171): Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
```

Don't know what going wrong please help..

This is what i added in Manifest

```
 <application
    android:name=".MyAppication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
```

here is my Class

```
public class MyAppications extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look at your server.

ACRA says that it has sent the error report to http://mylocal.ip/reportpath

What does the server that is listening at that address say in its logs?